# assign the returned value of wordpress function to a variable?

Tags: variables, categories

Why can't I store wp_list_categories in a variable?

```
        $wplist =   wp_list_categories( array (
                            'taxonomy'  => 'ntp_package_type',
                            'pad_counts'=> 0,
                            'title_li'  => '',
                            )
            );
var_dump($wplist); //null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the echo parameter to false. The function defaults to echoing the output rather than returning it.

```
$wplist = wp_list_categories(
    array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'ntp_package_type',
        'pad_counts' => 0,
        'title_li'   => '',
        'echo'       => false
    )
);
```